# Extract all the variables [NSNumber, NSDates, NSStrings, etc...] from entire XCode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Is there any way i can get all the variables declared [NSNumber, NSDates, NSStrings, etc...] from entire XCode project. Basically I want to use it for performing Localization.

I went through several tools which extracts strings only. What i need is all the types of variables as a result for each controllers in xcode project. Any such XCode plugin would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you localize `NSDate` or `NSNumber`? You are always localizing only strings or the conversion of the types to string.

Comment: Localization of dates and numbers are the jobs of `NSDateFormatter` and `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks. I want some mechanism or let's say some approach to identify strings, numbers, currency, etc... variables from entire existing project. Any script or xcode plugin which supports efficient way for such extraction?